# How to clear variables in python automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with csv files in pandas, these files are too big to be loaded at once so what I want to do is load once at a time, process it and load the next, something like this:

```
data_frame1  = pd.read_csv('first_file.csv')

#some processing 

# clear the variable here to free memory

data_frame2  = pd.read_csv('second_file.csv')
# some processing

....
....
....
```

Now, I know that:

```
%reset_selective data_frame1
```

will kill the variable but it puts a dialog this dialog:

```
Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])?
```

And I've to accept it in order to continue, I want to make this automatically so I don;t have to be in the computer just to press 'y'

Comment: Simply call your variable `data_frame` and re-use it, old data which is no longer referenced is collected automatically.

Comment: You do not need to manage Python's memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need to delete the variable at all. Python has automatic garbage collection, so if you assign a new DataFrame object to the same variable as your old one, the old one will be deleted automatically.

More specifically, variables in Python behave as references to objects, so as long as you don't create multiple variables pointing to the same DataFrame object, once you assign a new object to your variable, your old DataFrame object will no longer be referenced by any variable, and will therefore be removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Bad answer. There is a need, and you didn’t explain when GC occurs. Python will only GC for you if you use scopes. For global variables (like e.g. commonly used in IPython (notebook) sessions, `del` is a useful way to get rid of things you don’t want to stick around.

Answer (score 2):

`None` can be used to represent the absence of a value:

```
data_frame1 = None
```

Note: If you assign a new value to `data_frame1`, Python will automatically take care of the memory deallocation anyway, so this probably won't be necessary.

Comment: No, `x = None` means “I need to later check `if x is None`”. Use `del x`: It’s made for exactly “I want the variable gone”.

Answer (score 2):

Better than setting `x = None` is `del x`, which will remove its reference from memory entirely like it was never set, and automatically mark the object for garbage collection if it has no other references. See this:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> print x
5
>>> x = None
>>> print x
None
>>> del x
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but “remove it from memory” is misleading. As other said, variables in Python are references, so: `del` is a way to mark a not otherwise referenced object for garbage collection. For global variables (e.g. common in IPython), that’s useful!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the following command:

```
%reset_selective -f data_frame1
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is aware of this command but maybe not what the -f option does. It would be useful if you would explain what -f does in this command and why it solves the problem.